# is changing underlying type of an enum breaking change for wcf contract?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Assume I have a simple wcf service like so

```
[DataContract]
public enum VMType : int
{
    [EnumMember]
    Unknown = 0,

    [EnumMember]
    Virtual = 1,

    [EnumMember]
    Physical = 2,
}

[DataContract]
public class ClientRequest
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public VMType VMType { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    int GetStatus(ClientRequest request);
}
```

and if change the enum `VMType` to

```
public enum VMType : byte
{
```

Is this considered a breaking change ? Will old WCF clients still be able to connect to the new service host ?

As per [Enumeration Types in Data Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347875.aspx)

> Generally the data contract includes enumeration member names, not numerical values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this considered a breaking change ?

Yes.  This will change the serialization, which would be a breaking change.

> Will old WCF clients still be able to connect to the new service host ?

This depends a lot on the type of connection - in particular, which serializer is being used to map data.  Depending on the [binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733027) being used, this may or may not work.

Comment: Do you have any citation for **change the serialization** , According to MSDN the enumeration datatypes typically use **enumeration member names, not numerical values**

Comment: @parapurarajkumar It completely depends on the data contract being used.  Normally, enum will be serialized as a string, but there are exceptions, such as the JSON serializer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170.aspx)