# Skip Dictionary entry if key cannot be deserialized with DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, datacontractserializer

I am currently serializing a class that contains dictionaries likes this:

```
    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<SomeEnum, SomeData<long>> SomeDictionary = new Dictionary<SomeEnum, SomeData<long>>();
```

That works fine, but in the future I might want to remove a value from the enum. Currently I cannot deserialize data anymore if I remove an enum value. How do I instruct the DataContractSerializer to skip the dictionary entry if the key cannot be deserialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing the enum you are changing the contract - not a good practice ([Change enum change contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938364/is-changing-underlying-type-of-an-enum-breaking-change-for-wcf-contract))

If you want to go ahead, you'll have to implement custom serialization (e.g. [Custom JSON Serialization of enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643357/json-net-custom-serialization-of-a-enum-type-with-data-annotation)) and use the fact that .Net type `Enum` supports method `IsDefined()`...

```
enum myEnum { ev1, ev3 };
:
:    
Console.WriteLine($"{Enum.IsDefined(typeof(myEnum), "ev1")} {Enum.IsDefined(typeof(myEnum), "ev2")}");
```

giving

`True False`